# What is the general practice of establishing relationship in REST?

Tags: rest

How to model hierarchical relationship in rest api?

Let's say I want to add photo in an album, I can do this.

## 1

POST www.example.com/photo
POST www.example.com/album
POST www.example.com/addPhotoToAlbum?photoId={photoId}&albumId={albumId}

or I can do it in this way

## 2

POST www.example.com/album/{albumId}/photo/
But this way it will expose my server architecture.

or

## 3

POST www.example.com/album/addPhoto/albumId={albumId}

or

## 4

POST www.example.com/album/addPhoto/
with Json string {"albumId":123, "photoId":43543}

or

## 5

POST www.example.com/album/photo?photoId={}&albumId={}

REST Api is good for CRUD operation, but when it comes to how to establish relationship, 
If we are following object oriented style, #2 is great. if we are following database style, #5 is great

If we are using style #2, when we want to add comments to a particular photo, should we write this
POST www.example.com/album/{albumId}/photo/{photoId}/comment/
or just
POST www.example.com/photo/{photoId}/comment/

Question: What is the general practice of establishing relationship in REST?

Comment: #2 is my preferred method. How does #2 expose your server architecture? How would a consumer know if you were rewriting urls or not.  Also if you are using HATEOAS then the URL really doesn't matter. Because you would start at the bookmark, go to the album then post a picture to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some usefull points that help identify situations.

http://redrata.com/restful-uri-design/

Personally I like it when the URLS are short and ability to bookmark.